# Mac address spoofing in Kali resets back MAC addr. after connecting to WLAN

Tags: kali-linux

I use kali 2016.2 in virtualbox as root user.

First I change with macchanger my MAC addr. on 2 interfaces(eth0 and wlan0)

but after i connect to a network, the used interface(eth0 or wlan0) resets the MAC to the permanent(original) MAC and I dont know what to do, to stop this behaviour.

I appreciate every answer.

Comment: Did you try using a CLI to connect to the network? I personally would just change wlan0

Comment: Kali uses iproute2, `ip link set dev <DEVICE> address <ADDRESS>` is the proper way to handle address changes.  Also, you do not explain what do you mean by "connect to network", that may be interpreted in many ways and these are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Kali. Older versions from before the rolling releases don't seem to have this problem when running on real hardware (non-VM).

Comment: You should provide a reference to this.  Kali is still base on Debian, and I'm confident that I can use iproute2 on my Debian without issues.